# What is the basis of the trivial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why do we say that the set {$\vec 0$} has zero dimensions? I ask this because dimension, as defined in linear algebra, is the cardinality of a basis.

A basis with any actual elements, even {$\vec 0$} does not make sense as a basis as it violates the uniqueness property of creating elements in the space, and it has non trival relations.

So what exactly is the basis of {$\vec 0$}? If it were a set with no elements or the empty set, then how could we possibly construct $\vec 0$? Is there a way to create $\vec 0$ using a set containing nothing?

Comment: The only free family is the empty family, with cardinality 0

Comment: When you sum $0$ vectors, you get $\bar0$. That's a little handwavy, but it creates nice math, so we allow it. The same way that $0!=1$.

Comment: By convention, a sum over an empty set is $0$. This is analogous to the convention that an empty union is $\varnothing$. Along the same lines, an empty product is $1$ and an empty intersection is the whole space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sum_{x \in \varnothing}x = 0$, and $\varnothing$ is our basis.